# What happens to a Demon's Cover when the mortal providing part of that Cover dies?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Demon Dora buys from mortal Fred his childhood experiences in Townsville in return for fortune and fame.   Fred uses the money to buy a car, crashes, and dies.  Does anything happen to the Cover Dora crafted from those experiences?

Answer (score 2):

The pact ends with Fred’s death, but the Cover remains.

From the section on Pact Duration, p. 193:

“Pacts are usually permanent, lasting for as long as the contract exists and both parties live. They can be nullified, typically by destroying the contract, but otherwise continue to have their effects.”

The wording here is important (go figure for contract law). There is a difference between a Pact ending and being nullified.

So unless some special circumstance causes the Pact to be nullified at the time the pact ends, the effects continue. Fred’s heirs get the wealth. Dora keeps the cover.

If, for some special reason, the Pact nullifies, then Dora is in for a loss of a dot of Cover rating and has to check for a glitch. See the section on contract destruction for more info.

Also, Fred must have a pretty boring childhood in Townsville for this to be a valid contract. Even if he had only one close childhood friend, that relationship alone would be worth a 3 point (the maximum) cover benefit for a Pact.